# AWS s3:ListBucket action results in access denied using conditional StringLike statement on s3:prefix

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have items in a "folder" in an S3 bucket.  The "path" to the file contains the Identity ID of the user that uploaded the file and appears in the S3 managment console as "All Buckets/[MY_BUCKET]/us-east-1:080ffd35-c00e-4e33-877f-3ec57be4b128" I have an IAM policy attached to all Cognito authenticated users that includes the following conditional statement:

```
"Condition": {
            "StringLike": {
                "s3:prefix": [
                    "us-east-1:080ffd35-c00e-4e33-877f-3ec57be4b128/*"
                ]
            }
        }
```

I've hard-coded in the Identity ID as a troubleshooting step since I wasn't sure if "${cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:sub}" contained the correct string.  However even with a specific Identity ID encoded, it still does not work and I receive an access denied error when trying to list the contents of the bucket.  Am I correct in thinking that StringLike just looks for a given string inside the prefix?  Is there something else that I'm missing?

I've included my full IAM policy below:

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "s3:ListBucket"
        ],
        "Resource": [
            "arn:aws:s3:::[MY_BUCKET]"
        ],
        "Condition": {
            "StringLike": {
                "s3:prefix": [
                    "us-east-1:080ffd35-c00e-4e33-877f-3ec57be4b128/*"
                ]
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "s3:GetObject",
            "s3:PutObject",
            "s3:PutObjectAcl",
            "s3:GetObjectAcl"
        ],
        "Resource": [
            "arn:aws:s3:::[MY_BUCKET]/${cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:sub}*",
            "arn:aws:s3:::[MY_BUCKET]/${cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:sub}/*"
        ]
    }
]
```

}

Does the S3 bucket itself require any specific permissions settings on the S3 Management console to make this work properly and prevent the access denied error when trying to list the contents of the bucket?

**Additional Edit:**

1. A couple of questions that I wasn't able to figure out from the
   document. Is there a requirement for the bucket to have a policy?  I
   don't see anything in the documentation's examples that specify that
   the bucket needs a policy itself.
2. Does the bucket's permissions
   matter?  Once again, I didn't see anything about that specified in
   IAM policy documentation.

Comment: What do you mean by "it still does not work"? What are you trying to do (upload/download/list) and what error do you receive? Your policy looks similar to the one on [Understanding Amazon Cognito Authentication Part 3: Roles and Policies](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mobile/understanding-amazon-cognito-authentication-part-3-roles-and-policies/), so it should work.

Comment: I receive an access denied error when trying to list the contents of a bucket.

Comment: What's the specific S3 request you are making? If you are attempting a GET Bucket with prefix "", that wouldn't be allowed based on the StringLike s3:prefix condition you have. See also: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/writing-iam-policies-grant-access-to-user-specific-folders-in-an-amazon-s3-bucket/

Comment: As [Shannon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/602506/shannon) mentioned, it depends on how you call the "ListBucket"; do you explicitly set the prefix in your calls or do you expect the IAM policy to "do its magic"? See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/73600436/5112505 .

Answer (score 1):

List bucket can't be narrowed to a specific prefix like that. The list- bucket operation is done on the bucket itself so the condition and resource must be valid for the bucket.  I.e. The prefix condition doesn't match as that only is valid on the objects in the bucket not the bucket itself.

In the same way you can't limit list all buckets to only list certain buckets because that action is done on the service.

This is poorly but somewhat described in the docs: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/using-with-s3-actions.html#using-with-s3-actions-related-to-buckets

Comment: These two example from Amazon has them doing the exact same thing by using a condition to specify what portions of a bucket are viewable: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/access_policies_examples.html#iam-policy-example-s3-home-directory and http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/access_policies_examples.html#iam-policy-example-cognito so I'm pretty sure it is possible.