# AWS Cognito IAM policy - How to limit access to S3 folder (.NET SDK ListObjectsV2)

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-cognito, amazon-iam

I am trying to limit access for a Cognito user to specific folders in a bucket. The final target is to reach what is described [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_examples_s3_cognito-bucket.html) but I've simplified it for debugging.

The structure is as follows
MYBUCKET/111/content_111_1.txt
MYBUCKET/111/content_111_2.txt
MYBUCKET/222/content_222_1.txt
MYBUCKET/333/

I am performing a simple "list" call via the SDK.

```
using (AmazonS3Client s3Client = new AmazonS3Client(cognitoAWSCredentials))
{
  ListObjectsV2Request listRequest = new()
  {
    BucketName = "MYBUCKET"
  };
  ListObjectsV2Response listResponse = await s3Client.ListObjectsV2Async(listRequest);
}
```

I am authenticating via Cognito so I am updating *Cognito's IAM policy linked to the authenticated role*.

The following policy returns an S3 exception "Access Denied":

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "s3:ListBucket",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::MYBUCKET",
            "Condition": {
                "StringLike": {
                    "s3:prefix": [
                        "111",
                        "111/*"
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

The following policy returns all results (as expected).

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "s3:ListBucket",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::MYBUCKET"
        }
    ]
}
```

This is supposed to be super straightforward (see [here](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/writing-iam-policies-grant-access-to-user-specific-folders-in-an-amazon-s3-bucket/) ). There are other similar questions (such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40570417/aws-s3listbucket-action-results-in-access-denied-using-conditional-stringlike-s) and others) but with no final answer.

How should I write the IAM policy so that authenticated users can only access the contents of the folder "111"?

Best regards,

Andrej

Answer (score 0):

I hope I now understand what I got wrong."s3:prefix" is *not* some form of "filter that will only return the objects that match the prefix"; it is "a parameter that forces the caller to provide specific prefix information when executing the operation".

The following is taken from the [S3 documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/amazon-s3-policy-keys.html#condition-key-bucket-ops-2) :

[image]

To answer my own question, starting from the IAM policy above

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "s3:ListBucket",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::MYBUCKET",
            "Condition": {
                "StringLike": {
                    "s3:prefix": [
                        "111",
                        "111/*"
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

If I call the SDK with the code below, I will indeed get an "Access Denied" *because I have not specified a prefix that matches the IAM policy*.

```
using (AmazonS3Client s3Client = new AmazonS3Client(cognitoAWSCredentials))
{
  ListObjectsV2Request listRequest = new()
  {
    BucketName = "MYBUCKET"
  };
  ListObjectsV2Response listResponse = await s3Client.ListObjectsV2Async(listRequest);
}
```

But if I do specify the prefix in my SDK call, S3 will return the expected results i.e., only the ones "starting with 111".

```
using (AmazonS3Client s3Client = new AmazonS3Client(cognitoAWSCredentials))
{
  ListObjectsV2Request listRequest = new()
  {
    BucketName = "MYBUCKET",
    Prefix = "111"
  };
  ListObjectsV2Response listResponse = await s3Client.ListObjectsV2Async(listRequest);
}
```

In other words, my problem was not in the way I had written the IAM policy but in the way I was expecting the "s3:prefix" to work.